# Show overlay labels similar to that as shown in Apple iWatch Activity App

Tags: ios, xcode7, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm working on the iWatch application in which I have an UI design similar to that of the Activity app in the iWatch(screen shown below).

[image]

I'm not able to find solution to how to show the labels similar to that shown in the figure (Move, Exercise and Stand).
Is there a way to accomplish the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have an odd question - do you actually see those labels on your physical watch? I don't see those labels on my actual Apple Watch activity app. That might just be a marketing thing from Apple's website.

That aside, you could recreate how that image looks by having a group with three labels (Move, Stand, Exercise) and set the background image of the group that was the activity circles. Unfortunately, you won't be able to set a z-index to have controls overlap each other on the watch app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Anyway I found solution to the problem I was facing :)